# How do i simulate click on input checkbox when i remove a different element? ( Vanilla Js Solution)

Tags: javascript, checkbox

This is my HTML

```html
<div class="compareTrigger">
  <input id="firstInput" class="btn-compare-trigger" type="checkbox" <label for="firstInput" class="compare-label">compare</label>
</div>


<div class="compare-wrapper">

  <div class="compare-elements-wrapper">
    <div class="compare-element-item">
      <button class="btn-remove-item">Remove item</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

When I click on input checkbox, its state is `checked` and fires an event that creates elements that are in the compare-elements-wrapper.

When I click on `.btn-remove-item`, `compare-element-item` will be removed and i want my `firstInput` check-box to be unchecked and mimic an event that unchecks it. How do  I mimic click on checkbox, when I remove `compare-element-item`?

Comment: If there are two elements added to the `compare-wrapper` element should the `<input>` be unchecked, or only if all elements are removed? Also, can you share the function that adds the content?

Comment: I have multiple checkboxes , each creates a compare-element-item. When i delete compare-element-item , i also want my checkbox that created my element to be unchecked and mimic a click on it. Without mimic the click on it , i would have to click it twice in order to create that element again .

Comment: Where's the JavaScript? See [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `checked` attribute of the checkbox element to `false` if you want to uncheck it :

```js
// Get the remove button element
const removeButton = document.getElementById("removeButton");

removeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const firstInputCheckBox = document.getElementById("firstInput");
  // Uncheck the input
  firstInputCheckBox.checked = false;
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="firstInput">
<label for="firstInput" class="compare-label">compare</label><br />

<button type="button" id="removeButton">Remove item</button><br />
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `yourElement.checked = !yourElement.checked` to toggle it from checked to unchecked or the opposite, depending of its state :

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementById("toggleButton");

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const firstInputCheckBox = document.getElementById("firstInput");
  // Toggle the input
  firstInputCheckBox.checked = !firstInputCheckBox.checked;
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="firstInput">
<label for="firstInput" class="compare-label">compare</label><br />

<button type="button" id="toggleButton">Toggle checkbox</button>
```

---

If you want to trigger the event `click` on the checkbox, you can first create a [`new Event('click')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) and then, [`dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) it

```js
const firstInputCheckBox = document.getElementById("firstInput");

firstInputCheckBox.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(`the checkbox was clicked and it's now ${firstInputCheckBox.checked ? '' : 'un'}checked`)
});

// Get the remove button element
const removeButton = document.getElementById("removeButton");

removeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  
  // Uncheck the input
  firstInputCheckBox.checked = false;
  const clickEvent = new Event('click');
  firstInputCheckBox.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="firstInput">
<label for="firstInput" class="compare-label">compare</label><br />

<button type="button" id="removeButton">Remove item</button><br />
```

Comment: If i just uncheck my input , i have to double check it  then , when i want to add the item i just removed. That's the reason i want to also simulate a click when i removed that element.

Comment: I just noticed that part in your question, about firing the event, I'm actually editing my answer to complete it

Comment: Thank youuu so much!

Comment: You are welcome, someday it will be your turn to help others :)

Answer (score 0):

With `click()` function

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn-remove-item").onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById("firstInput").click();
    };
```

Old answer with checked false

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn-remove-item").onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById("firstInput").checked = false;
    };
```

Comment: It doesn't help , because an unchecked element isn't equal with clicking on it, that's why i want to  mimic the click event when i delete that element .

Comment: Hey! I think you can try .click() like in the updated answer, I guess it will help! +1 it helps :)